# I can't set value of enum in class

Tags: java, android, enums

When I try to pass enum variable as argument to the class this way:

```
MyClass newObjectMyClass = new MyClass(EnumArgument.AAA);
```

and then I try to set this argument value as new variable or pass it to next class:

```
public class MyClass {
    EnumArgument xarg;

    public MyClass(EnumArgument qarg) {
        xarg = qarg;
    }

    EnumArgument new = xarg;

    NextClass nextClassObject = new NextClassObject(xarg);

    public void move(Canvas can) {
        Log.i("info", "xarg = " + xarg + "   nextClassObject.doSomething = " + nextClassObject.doSomething + " new = " + new);
        nextClassObject.doSomething(can);
    }
}
```

Logcat show me something like that:

> I/info:﹕ xarg = AAA    nextClassObject.doSomething = null new = null
>   threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception

As you see, logcat shows me my "xarg" value well, but "new" variable as null... "new" should have same value as xarg, I'm right?

(I just write this code to show you what I mean, if there is any error it is just probably my mistake.)

I think there is some logical error.
When I put this line:

```
NextClass nextClassObject = new NextClassObject(xarg);
```

to my `move` method it works well.

Comment: Post real and clear code. Also post the code you have tried.

Comment: Please follow Java code conventions. Type names (classes, interfaces, enums) should start with an uppercase letter and each word in the name starts with another uppercase letter (e.g. `NextClass`, `EnumArgument`). Method and variable names should be the same, but with the first letter in lowercase (e.g. `doSomething`). They should also be meaningful. And indentation is important.

Comment: This is real and most clear code what i can post... In my program is same code, but with others variables name and much more methods, variables etc. but this part of code is same. Everything else work perfect. There is probbably just logical error, something what i dont understand, if you know what it can be, just tell me.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Ye, you have right, but its not source of my problem. Anyway thanks for your advice. If somebody have any idea why "xnew" dont have same value as "xarg", just let me know.

Comment: This isn't properly android-specific and your problem seems android specific, so I don't think this is a proper MVCE (Minimal verifiable complete example). That, and I renamed the variables and class names to match Java code convention so it'd look less like a mess.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thank you. Belive me or not, but this part of code + logcat note, show exactly my problem. There is no sense to put more code...

Comment: You really need to use better names, man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, *initializers* are invoked **before** constructors.

So when you call `new Myclass(EnumArgument.AAA)`, memory is allocated. First, all the fields get default values. So it is as if these instructions were performed:

```
xarg = null;
new = null;  // The name "new" is actually illegal
nextClassObject = null;
```

That's because the default value for reference variables is `null`.

The next stage is to calculate and assign the initializers. You have two initializers:

```
EnumArgument new = xarg;
NextClass nextClassObject = new NextClassObject(xarg);
```

So you assign the value of `xarg` to `new`. But from the previous stage, `xarg` is `null`, so `new` is also `null` now. `nextClassObject` receives a new, non-null object reference - but the argument to the constructor of `NextClassObject` is `null`!

**Then the constructor is called**.

```
public MyClass(EnumArgument qarg) {
    xarg = qarg;
}
```

So now you put the value of your argument - `EnumArgument.AAA` - in `xarg`. So the value of `xarg` is `AAA`, but the value of `new` is **`null`**, because it was set up in the previous stage, before the constructor assigned the value to `xarg`.

If you want `new` to contain the value from the argument, you are not supposed to initialize it with an initializer, but assign a value to it in the constructor:

```
public MyClass(EnumArgument qarg) {
    xarg = qarg;
    new = xarg;
}
```

It would be better if you keep all the field declarations strictly before the constructors and methods. That way you won't be confused about the order of execution.

Comment: Wow, man. You're awesome, thanks alot. You give me perfect answer, i knew there is something illogicall in way of my thinking, but i didnt knew what exactly, now i understand everything. I'm your fan, man.